# reversing this math expression in C#

Tags: c#, math

I have a lot of dislikes on this post, I'm not sure why, but for letting you guys help me out with this question, I will give you this script as a gift. This script converts experience to level and from level to experience points given an exponential expression. those constants ensure that level 100 will equal 10 million experience. In Runescape, their level 99 equals 13,032,xxx which is a strange number.

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
const float salt = 2.82842712474619f;
const float factor = 0.64977928f;
const int lvl_100_XP = 10000000;

static void Main()
{
    int xp = 9717096;// lvl 99
    int lvl = ExperienceToLevel(xp);
    Console.WriteLine("LVL: " + lvl.ToString()+ " XP: " + LevelToExperience(lvl).ToString());
}
static public int ExperienceToLevel(int xp){
    int lvl = 0;
    if (xp == lvl_100_XP){//9999987 is lvl 100 due to roundoff issues so it is fixed to 10mill
        lvl = 100;
    }
    else{
        lvl = (int)((1f / salt) * (float)Math.Pow((float)xp, (1f - factor)));
        if (lvl == 0){
            //lvl = 1;
        }
    }
    if (lvl == 100 && xp < lvl_100_XP){
           lvl = 99;
    }
    return lvl;
}

static public int LevelToExperience(int lvl){
    int xp = 0;
    if (lvl == 100){//9999987 is lvl 100 due to roundoff issues so it is fixed to 10mill
        xp = lvl_100_XP;
    }
    else{

        xp = (int)Math.Exp((float)Math.Log(salt * (float)lvl) / (1f - factor))+1;

        if (xp <= 1){
            xp= 0;
        }
        if (lvl == 100){
            xp = lvl_100_XP;
        }
    }
    return xp;
}
}
```

Comment: The reverse of "power-ofs" is "log-ofs"

Comment: Ya I found that too on the internet but I don't know how to apply it to this function specifically...the numbers just don't return what I want them to.

Comment: @Hogan it wouldent be a log, we would use log if we where trying to find `c` but we know `c` it is just a root. So `exp = Math.Pow(d, 1/c)` the problem I am not sure how to solve is is finding `d` from `lvl`

Comment: With meaningful variable names like a, b, c, d, I'm surprised you'd get confused.

Comment: If anybody can figure this out...you are truly a math genius haha. The other point I like about this formula is the fact that it is exponential and retrieves lvl 100 at 10,000,000. if there is an alternative to get the same result, that would also be good. The hard part here is getting exp from 'b' and 'd'. It looks simple but I don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: To get lvl 100 at 10,000,000, just divide 10,000,000 by 100,000.

Comment: ya but then how could I get 9717095 = 99. I don't want to have an array of levels = experience for each milestone, I want the expression to create these levels both by creating and retrieving.

Comment: You are having a hard time finding the bug in part because the code you wrote is actively resisting your attempts to understand it.  Start by making it an exemplar of good style.  `ExperienceToLevel`, not `exp2lvl`, abbrvs r cool 2 13yos, not engineers. Give your variables meaningful names that reflect their purposes.  Mark constants as `const`. Put shared constants in class scope. And so on.  Once you have a program that you can actually read, it will be a lot easier to find the mistake.

Comment: Alright I will edit the code to be more readable. give me one moment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's work it out.

Let `x` be the experience, `a` and `c` are constants. `L` is the level. We notate exponentiation as `^`; note that C# does not have such an operator. `^` in C# is XOR.

You have

```
b = x / a
d = x ^ c
L = b / d
```

so that's

```
L = x / (a * x ^ c)
```

which is

```
L = (1 / a) * (x / x ^ c)
```

which is

```
L = (1 / a) * x ^ (1 - c)
```

You wish to solve for x.  So multiply both sides by 'a':

```
a * L = x ^ (1 - c)
```

Take the ln of both sides. (Or whatever logarithm you like best.)

```
ln (a * L) = (1 - c) ln (x)
```

Divide both sides by 1 - c

```
ln (a * L) / (1 - c) = ln x
```

And eliminate the ln; remember that exp is the inverse of ln. If you used some other logarithm, then use some other exponent.

```
exp (ln (a * L) / (1 - c)) = x
```

And we're done.

Comment: High school algebra to the rescue.

Comment: Man it looks simple! maybe I need to go back to school hehe it's been a while. I got this far float x = (float)Math.Log(a * (float)lvl) / (1f - c); and now I have no idea how you get the final result. so close oh man!!!

Comment: @CoreySt-Jacques: The inverse of Math.Log is Math.Exp, as I noted in the answer.

Comment: Ohh!! I didnt know math.exp was a function haha. You know your stuff...thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, exp to level is a *many to one* relationship. The reverse is a *one to many*, so what exp are you aiming to return in `lvl2exp`? The minimum for that level? The maximum? A mean value?

I think your better off just computing once a table  with experience brackets for each level (even cache it to a file if its not going to change) and simply doing a binary search to find the corresponding bracket for any given level.

Comment: You're totally right, well from zero to 200 it is lvl 1, and from 201 to 440 it is lvl 2. I don't know these values by heart, all I know is that these lvl to experience ratios are created automatically up to 10 million for lvl 100. I guess if there is no easy way of doing this formula reversed, then I will create a table....although if there is a smart mind out there who can figure this out without a table, much and great credit would be pointed toward you my friend and you should get a job at the pentagone haha ok maybe not but it is a mystery how to solve this...